# How to put unhandled errors into a log file - Python logging

Tags: python, logging, unhandled-exception

I am trying to log all kinds of errors into the log file. (unhandled exceptions is NOT being logged into the log file.)

For example inside my function i have:

```
i = "hello"
x = i /3
```

gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

I want to put this error into the log file without having to add a pre-defined line of `logger.error` in my functions as I won't be aware what errors I might get during runtime. Hope I'm making sense.

I tried searching a lot but can't find any answers to this issue

I tried

```py
print = logger.info
```

but turns out its useless as it doesn't help in errors and I understand that its a terrible way to write code

My code so far:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s:%(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] -[%(name)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d]- %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')

LOG_FILENAME = 'check.log'
LOG_FILENAME = os.path.join(get_datadir_path(), LOG_FILENAME)
f_handler = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME) 
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

c_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Either you don't have try/except block : the whole code will stop, OR you have try/except block and you need to put `mylogger.error()` in it

Comment: Unhandled errors are propagated, so you theoretically only need to have one `try` / `except` at your program's entry point to catch all of them and log them using `logger.error` or `logger.exception`.

Comment: _"as I won't be aware what errors I might get during runtime"_ - why would you need to know which exceptions are raised? Just catch them all!

Comment: thanks a lot @zvone it helped a lot :) tho i was already using try/except, your suggestion of *"program's entry point to catch all of them"* did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try`, `except` and `logger.exception`:

```py
try:
    i = "hello"
    x = i / 3
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception('Exception!')
    raise  # you can also raise the exception to stop running after logging
```

`except Exception` will catch all non-exit exceptions (but it is a too broad exception clause). Or use `except BaseException` to catch all kinds of exceptions, like `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Then the exception is logged into your logfile:

```
01-Jan-23 22:33:48 - [ERROR] -[root:<module>:29]- Exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/xxx.py", line 27, in <module>
    x = i / 3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```